# Inserting selected row in ListBox to Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

My ListBox is a 4 column ListBox and I am inserting the last 3 columns of data within.

I managed to put together a code that inserts the nth row of ListBox into the appropriate cells in the spreadsheet. However, what I would like is to insert whichever row a user selects from the ListBox... And if they choose nothing, it will not insert anything.

My code for inserting nth row is:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n as integer
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row
n = inputbox("enter value")
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("F" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(1, n)
    .Range("G" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(2, n)
    .Range("H" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(3, n)
End With
```

Can you please advise on how to modify my code to choosing the selected value rather than nth? And how to not insert if not selected?

Comment: Your code is assuming that the `InputBox` will return a value that can be implicitly converted to an `Integer`. Instead assign the `InputBox` result to a `String`, and then you can do `If StrPtr(result) = 0` to see if the inputbox was cancelled, and `If IsNumeric(result)` to *know* that you're looking at a value that can be converted to an `Integer`. Then do `n = CInt(result)` for an explicit conversion.

Comment: That said I've no idea what "choosing the selected value rather than nth" means. Isn't `n` the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only allow one item to be selected, then you can simply reference the `.Value` of your listbox element.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n as integer
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row
n = ListBox1.Value
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("F" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(1, n)
    .Range("G" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(2, n)
    .Range("H" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(3, n)
End With
```

If you allow multiple items to be selected, then you will need to loop through each item in the listbox and use `.Selected(n)` to determine if the item is selected.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n as integer
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row
For n = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(n) Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("F" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(1, n)
            .Range("G" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(2, n)
            .Range("H" & LastRow + 1) = ListBox1.Column(3, n)
        End With
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: Hey - I tried your first solution. It gives me a runtime error '6': Overflow. What does that mean?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? It typically means you've tried to assign a value too large for the variable.

Comment: I tried to declare 'n' as Long instead. Error changes to 'Could not get the Column property. Invalid property array index'

Comment: Which line is highlighted in the debugger?